# For phone jack, which terminals are used by modem?

Tags: data-wiring, socket, telephone, phone-wiring

I have a new telephone jack to replace the old on the wall outlet. The new jack is confusing and I'm new to this. I think I may have messed with the wiring, and I don't understand which wire should go to which terminal. The purpose of the jack is so it can only connect to a ADSL modem and not for any phone. The telephone cable, is made up of two wires, blue and white. Heres how I connected to the new telephone jack:

[image]

As you can see, blue and white wire. And 4 terminals. On the jack itself, they are just numbered from 1 to 4. Im gonna guess these are L1, L2, TS, TX? Or does it mean something else? Each terminal has two holes. What i did was just connect to 1 and 2, because i didnt know what else to do. Was it supposed to be 1 and 3? or 1 and 4? The internet works after wired it, but the upstream is lower than before, 50% lower. Should I just leave it as is, as it probably doesnt matter which wire goes where?

Also side note, Ive shortened the thin wires I have because telephone jack screw system bends and nicks it. Should I not shorten it everytime I rewire? I now have a very short wire as a result and makes things difficult.

edit: heres a manual for the type of phone jack im using, look to the right of first page: http://e-catalogue.legrand.ru/upload/files/LE07456AB.pdf

and here is a video of someone installing exact same: https://youtu.be/m8ffHiIOzw0?t=87

Comment: ADSL is very sensitive to line noise and can be finicky. It sounds to me based on your comments that your wiring is OK but perhaps your jack is allowing some cross-talk or other interference. I'd post a real answer except I'm not knowledgeable enough to give any real info and don't have the time to research it, but if somebody else agrees I'd love to see a real answer. You could try a higher quality jack, perhaps one specifically designed for ADSL with a built in filter, or by adding a filter (http://bit.ly/2bHwFFR for example is a nice wall mount filter with a proper phone splitter output).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to connect to the **center** two wires in RJ-11. Since RJ-11 is usually 6 pins, these are pins 3 and 4. If yours has only 4 pins, these should be pins 2 and 3. Leave the other pins unconnected.

Now, with regards to the colors (and correct polarity), this is country-dependent. Check [this chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector#6P2C) for reference. But, you can also try one way, and if it doesn't work, switch the wires.

Comment: even though its working now, its still wrong? Im gonna try the center, but are you refering to pins 2, 3 as in the pic i provided or is that standard reference? Also I shouldnt cut anymore wire when i make the switch?

Comment: RJ-11's (as phone jacks) have a design which accommodates 6 pins, but in practice, only 4 pins have ever been used.

Comment: You shouldn't be cutting or breaking off the wires for obvious reasons.  Release them from their terminal - unscrew the screw, do whatever you do to release a jab connection, etc.

Comment: RJ-11 has always been 4 pins. 6 pins is an RJ-25.

Comment: @BillOertell: If you want to be that precise, then, no, you're incorrect too. RJ-11 is one-line (two wires), RJ-14 is two-line (four wires) and RJ-25 is three lines (six wires), all using the same physical connector format. I haven't seen real RJ-11 in years, they all are either RJ-14 or RJ-25, but are called RJ-11 for simplicity's sake.

Comment: @Altoban If it's working now then what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Jason i fear that wrong wiring may have led to lower upstream speed. Used to have it 50% higher before tampering with outlets.

Comment: @Altoban Just asking the obvious first: Are you sure you seated the wires properly in the connectors? E.g. stripped the proper amount off the ends, proper insertion, turned the thingy securely with the screw driver, etc. Also have you tried swapping out a known good cable between the modem and the wall jack just to rule that out?

Comment: @Altoban if it's working at all then you have to correct pair, degraded speed would be caused by introduction of noise or EMV.  Incorrect wire?

Comment: @Jason C They seated well and stripped okay i guess, should be find. The cable i swapped and its the same. But when i add a splitter between modem and wall, the modem doesnt pick up the dsl and just keeps flashing.

Comment: @Altoban DSL is pretty sensitive to line noise. Your modem should have a phone output on the back and that's what you should connect the phone to, rather than using a splitter (you can use a splitter plugged into the back of the modem for multiple phones, but you don't want to use one between the modem and the wall). Otherwise you'll have to install proper filtering. Also consider a higher quality wall jack, you could be getting some crosstalk in there as well.

Comment: @Tyson here are the two speeds, different routers but doesnt matter its all the same https://i.imgur.com/qERoFg6.png   Cant be incorrect wire, as it was working before.

Comment: @haimg, most RJ-11 jacks have 4 pins, probably from the time when the outer pins were used for power for phones like Princesses and old Trimlines. While I have seen 2-pin RJ-11 jacks, they're rare. You usually only see 6-pin jacks for applications where 3 lines are required. aka RJ-25+. But they do all fall under what could be called an RJ-11 sized jack (as opposed to RJ45 sized).

Answer (score 0):

According to your graphic you supplied you have it reversed.The White conductor terminated on the 1 posistion, The blue on the 2.

Comment: You have the blue and white reversed.